# Styling the background color of pandas index cell

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I want to change the background styling color of the pandas table.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'group': ['A','B','C','D'],
'var1': [38, 1.5, 30, 4],
'var2': [29, 10, 9, 34],
'var3': [8, 39, 23, 24],
'var4': [7, 31, 33, 14],
'var5': [28, 15, 32, 14]
})

df.set_index('group', inplace=True)
```

I want the background color of the index cell (and just the index cell) A,C in blue and B,D in red.

I looked at the styling documentation but I could not find an example that matches this case.

Comment: It is not implemented AFAIK:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Limitations *You can only style the values, not the index or columns*

Comment: @anky ok... (i was expecting that answer) Do you know how to color the whole row according to that index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is not currently available and the next release for this might be December 2021 (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/41893). However, you can easily work around this by using table styles. See my answer below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]], index=["A", "B", "C", "D"])
green = [{'selector': 'th', 'props': 'background-color: green'}]
red = [{'selector': 'th', 'props': 'background-color: red'}]
df.style.set_table_styles({"A": green, "B": red, "C": green, "D": red}, axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: You can also now use pandas `map_index` and `apply_index` functions

Answer (score 4):

Based on the limitations of [`df.style`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Limitations), coloring index and columns is not implemented.

If you are okay to color the values based on the index, you can do something like this. Create a dictionary and apply the color based on the index using `index.map`

```
c1 = 'background-color: blue'
c2 = 'background-color: red'
d = {"A":c1,"B":c2,"C":c1,"D":c2}

df.style.apply(lambda x: x.index.map(d))
```

---

[image]

Comment: Yep, great choice! Do you know why if I use 'C0' instead of 'red' the code do nothing?

Answer (score 2):

We can manipulate the underlying HTML via looking at `<th>` tags. One convenient way is with the [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# get the HTML representation
html = df.to_html()

# form the soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# the color categories
blues = {"A", "C"}
reds = {"B", "D"}

# for each possible "table header" tag...
for tag in soup.find_all("th"):
    # if tag's content is in `blues`...
    if tag.text in blues:
        # change the HTML style attribute accordingly
        tag["style"] = "background-color: blue;"
    # similar here..
    elif tag.text in reds:
        tag["style"] = "background-color: red;"

# get back the new HTML
new_html = str(soup)
```

Then, in an IPython notebook for example:

```
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML(new_html)
```

gives

[image]

Comment: great job! but I still have two questions. 1) Do you know why tag.text is printing some but not all the indexes? (in the true df not in this simplified example) 2) Why if instead of 'red' I put 'C0' the code do nothing?

Comment: Hi @FedericoVega, 1) if `tag.text` is neither in `blues` set nor `reds` set as defined above, then it won't be colored at all. So if for example there was another group named `E`, it won't be colored because it doesn't satisfy two `if`s there. 2) `C0` is not a valid HTML color I believe; can you clarify on what `C0` is supposed to result in? A close value is `#C00` which is hexadecimal representation of a color and please note the `#` in front. If I do this instead of `red` above as `"background-color: #C00;"`, then I get something similar to red in color for `B` and `D` rows.